# How to talk about feeling hot without referring to sexuality?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

"I am feeling hot", I said to my father, of course referring to weather.

He said that that sentence conveys that you are referring to sex and you should not use such sentences.

How should I convey that I am hot due to weather only?

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with the sentence "I am feeling hot". Alternatively, you can say I am feeling warm.

Comment: Your father is confused between - you *feeling hot* and *you are hot*! :)

Comment: I agree, Ive never heard anyone say "feel hot" to mean anything sexual. Even if it was, I dont think its an issue. Technically "Im wet" is sexual, but if someone says that having been in the ocean, nobody is going to take it the wrong way.

Comment: There is a difference between *is* sexual and *can  be* sexual. "I'm wet" is the latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a sweltering day, the intended meaning should be picked up on easily enough. But your father might be helping you out by pointing out a potential double-entendre – sometimes those can be embarrassing if said around the wrong group of people. For example, if a teenage girl is surrounded by teenage boys, "I feel hot" might not be the best way to word her feelings about the hot day. (Even if they know what she means, they might start snickering anyway.)

You ask for an alternative, so I'll give you one:

> This heat is killing me.

That's a bit figurative, too, so you could also say:

> This heat is really getting to me.

Here's another one:

> I'm not enjoying this hot weather.

Most of the time, though, "I'm feeling hot" is just fine by itself, and there's no need to find a more ‘sterile’ alternative. Most people know what you mean when you're talking about the heat in a room, or the heat outside on a sweltering day. I'm not recommending that the phrase be avoided altogether, but it's worth remembering that it *can* be interpreted in more than one way.

---

NOTE: Some earlier comments seemed to be skeptical about this double meaning, so I'll back my assertion up with a few examples. When these bloggers write:

> Pick a dress that compliments your figure. If you’re wearing red, you want to look and [feel hot!](http://www.lapetitepear.com/valentines-day-style/)
>
> If you [feel hot](https://jooleea.wordpress.com/category/fashion/), then you’ll look hot. Confidence is your greatest accessory.
>
> The point is that you will be dressing to impress him somehow, while you make yourself [feel hot](http://www.the-editeur.com/blog/2013/02/what-to-wear-this-valentines-day/) and confident.

they are not meaning that you'll need to sit near a fan and sip a cold drink to cool off. Moreover, these authors were dishing out some fashion advice for Valentine's Day (which is celebrated in February), so we can be pretty sure that weren't talking about hot weather, either.

That said, even in fashion circles, the phrase can be used both ways. There's a big difference between *hot & confident* and *hot & itchy*. Check out these excerpts:

> Don't wear anything that’s going to make you [feel hot](http://www.kingandallen.co.uk/blog/the-ka-guide-to-dressing-for-a-hot-date/). Sweaty is not sexy.
>
> The long sleeves will help keep the direct sun off of your arms but without making you [feel hot](http://momblogsociety.com/feel-classy-and-be-beach-ready-with-acevog-dresses/) and sticky.

In those sentences, follow-on remarks make it clear that "feel hot" in that context wasn't intended to mean "feel sexy."

Comment: much thankful again, btw, those alternative examples are quite long to speak. :)

Comment: My first example is only one syllable more than your original. :^)

Comment: +1. Here's one with fewer syllables:   *I hate this heat.* Or, *I'm sweltering*.

Answer (score 7):

Your father is wrong.  In part.  "I am feeling hot" is the non-sexual phrase, which *also* has a sexual meaning, which is coming to be understood and used more.

The problem with **all** non-sexual phrasings - e.g. "I'm feeling the heat" - is that they are vulnerable to double-entendre.

Comment: '*feeling* hot' has no sexual context, IMO. I'd say - *I'm feeling horny*.

Comment: "I'm feeling horny" is *explicitly* sexual.  "I'm feeling hot" is open to interpretation.

Comment: By no means, 'feel' hot is related to 'sexuality'. Though you got my +1 :)

Comment: Decades of double-entendre disagree with you.  e.g. the Marilyn Monroe movie title "Some Like It Hot". But thank you for the +1

Comment: You aren't getting me... I'm **strictly talking** about 'feel hot'.

Comment: @Maulik - In the middle of a hot summer day, "I feel hot" usually means what we think it means. However, the phrase can still be used suggestively, as Euan says. If you don't believe us, try Googling ["feel hot" "wear lingerie"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22feel+hot%22+%22wear+lingerie%22) for a few examples :^)

Comment: @J.R. This is very strange to me then! I'd have certainly used there 'if you want to 'look' hot'.

Comment: The difference between _looking hot_ and _feeling hot_ is one of perception: There is some overlap, but the first is largely about how others see you, while the second is more about how you feel about yourself – it's tied more closely to self-confidence. Then there's the expression "I feel hot to trot," which is even _more_ suggestive.

Comment: @Maulik And you're not getting me : no matter how strict you are (ooh err, fnarr, fnarr) in talking about the phrase 'feel hot', interpretation is in the ear of the beholder.  And it is certainly *possible* to interpret the phrase other than as an innocent expression of how the day's weather is affecting you.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I convey that I am hot due to weather only?

To refer to the weather being hot/uncomfortable due to heat, you could use any of these, in addition to what other answers have already mentioned:

- It's boiling!
- I don't like this scorching heat.
- What a hateful muggy weather it is!
- I am sweltering!